# Get nested object with one query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following model

```
type Instance struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name               string `gorm:"unique;"`
    UserID             uint
    GroupID            uint
    StackID            uint
    RequiredParameters []InstanceRequiredParameter `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"requiredParameters,omitempty"`
    OptionalParameters []InstanceOptionalParameter `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"optionalParameters,omitempty"`
    DeployLog          string                      `gorm:"type:text"`
}

type InstanceRequiredParameter struct {
    gorm.Model
    InstanceID               uint                   `gorm:"index:idx_instance_required_parameter,unique"`
    StackRequiredParameterID uint                   `gorm:"index:idx_instance_required_parameter,unique"`
    StackRequiredParameter   StackRequiredParameter `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Value                    string
}

type InstanceOptionalParameter struct {
    gorm.Model
    InstanceID               uint                   `gorm:"index:idx_instance_optional_parameter,unique"`
    StackOptionalParameterID uint                   `gorm:"index:idx_instance_optional_parameter,unique"`
    StackOptionalParameter   StackOptionalParameter `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Value                    string
}

type StackRequiredParameter struct {
    gorm.Model
    StackID uint   `gorm:"index:idx_name_required_parameter,unique"`
    Name    string `gorm:"index:idx_name_required_parameter,unique"`
}

type StackOptionalParameter struct {
    gorm.Model
    StackID uint   `gorm:"index:idx_name_optional_parameter,unique"`
    Name    string `gorm:"index:idx_name_optional_parameter,unique"`
}
```

I'm trying to get an instance with parameters and the StackRequiredParameter/StackOptionalParameter retrived as well since I need the Name property.

I can do it with the following function

```
func (r instanceRepository) FindWithParametersById(id uint) (*model.Instance, error) {
    var instance *model.Instance
    err := r.db.First(&instance, id).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var requiredParameters []model.InstanceRequiredParameter
    err = r.db.
        Where("instance_id = ?", id).
        Preload("StackRequiredParameter").
        Find(&requiredParameters).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var optionalParameters []model.InstanceOptionalParameter
    err = r.db.
        Where("instance_id = ?", id).
        Preload("StackOptionalParameter").
        Find(&optionalParameters).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    instance.RequiredParameters = requiredParameters
    instance.OptionalParameters = optionalParameters

    return instance, nil
}
```

But that takes 3 queries. Can anyone suggest a way to do it with just one query using Gorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with something like this:

```
func (r instanceRepository) FindWithParametersById(id uint) (*model.Instance, error) {
    var instance *model.Instance
    err := r.db.Preload("RequiredParameters.StackRequiredParameter").Preload("OptionalParameters.StackOptionalParameter").First(&instance, id).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return instance, nil
}
```

It will still perform multiple queries in your database, because each `Preload` call runs a separate query, but at least you don't have to write all that code.